# Open Source Specification of the APL Language?

Tags: specifications, apl

Ruby has [Ruby Spec](http://rubyspec.org/).

Does APL have anything (open source) close to this available? A list of expected inputs and outputs at least? Or some sort of core specification for the APL language?

Comment: "Not constructive"? What's debatable about there being a spec or not?

Comment: I think they mistook "apl" for "api" :) They did not answer any questions with tag "APL". Moreover "spec" tag is rather indefinite as it has no description what it could mean. I don't have the power to reopen your question.

Comment: I agree, this question should be reopened. Whether there is a spec is a fairly factual question, not a matter of opinion. Users might also point to documents or references that serve the purpose of a spec. I don't see why this should be closed.

Answer (score 7):

See Iverson's [Dictionary of APL](http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/APLDictionary.htm).  The end notes contain many references that may also be useful. In addition, the jsoftware site also has many resources related to APL.